# Show previously introduced value dropdown menu Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

My app has posts and categories.

When creating a new post, it shows all the empty fields and a dropdown menu to select the category.

Once filled out, the user clicks on a Preview button which shows the post as it will be published. Then he has two buttons, *post It* and *Make Changes*.

When clicking the *Make Changes* button the app returns to the create view with all the fields loaded, but the dropdown menu does not keep the category selected before.

Is it any way of implementing this functionality? Below some lines of my code:

In my new view:

```
  <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select one!") %>
```

In my new controller:

```
  @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
```

In my create controller when clicking button *Make Changes*

```
  @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }   
  render :new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the selected item as one of the options in options_for_select

```
<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories, selected: :category_id), :prompt => "Select one!") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The SteveTurczyn's answer worked, but I had to pass the currently selected :category_id this way:

```
<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories, selected: @post.category_id), :prompt => "Select one!") %>
```